# htaccess not redirecting to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /films/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/films/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want it to redirect automatically the url to https
But it is not redirecting. I tried changing

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/films/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/films/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to https, you can use the following redirect in  `/films/.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /films/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/films/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this redirect.

Comment: After using https, my css is not working. Is their not any way that css and js files also redirect automatically to https @starkeen

Comment: This redirects everything to https from the /films folder. Where are those files located?

Comment: in the films folder, their are files and i have taken some css and js links directly from a link , from the domain itself like http://www.example.com/ @starkeen

Answer (score 3):

To force `HTTPs` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Therefore leaving you with `https://` on everything. Including `{REQUEST_URI}` is better than specifying the directory. As it will then work for all directories also.

As I recently learnt, it is better to combine your forced `www` and `https`, try using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have to use this code as it is or change anything? @thickguru

Comment: Just use it as is.

Comment: Where to place the code. Do i need to remove any code from my htaccess. @thickguru

Comment: Just place in your .htaccess below your force www

Comment: See my edit in answer, combining both your forced www and https. You can replace your current forced www with that.